Why am I getting slow transfer speeds on USB 3.0 to SATA connector?
I was transferring (copying) a huge game file of about 100GB from my laptop to the SATA SSD I already have using the SATA to USB 3.0 (male) connector. Sometimes it does work properly, i.e I do get to see speeds above 300MB/s but many times I see that (including this case) I get about 40MB/s on the same connector, same laptop and the same SATA SSD which is definitely unacceptable for USB 3.0. What happens is as soon as I start transferring something it just stays at 30-35MB/s all the time instead of 300-400MB/s.
I checked this with other laptops as well that supports USB 3.0, but again the same problem, sometimes you do get to see 300-400MB/s but most of the times you just get to see very low transfer speeds.
I want to know what exactly can be the bottlenecking part of this setup or if that's how the USB 3.0 treats the huge files or is there something wrong with my device itself.
System details:

Intel core i5-13450HX
Zebronics SATA to USB converter
WD Green 480GB SATA SSD


Which exact model of the SSD? Do you know which flash type it uses (TLC or QLC)?

Sounds like a bad connector on the USB side that sometimes causes the connection to degrade to USB 2.0. (On Linux you can easily confirm if that has happened by checking lsusb -t.)

lsusb on itself tells which device you ought to look for in the -t list.

Flash devices has a tendency to have a stated 'possible speed' as (e.g.) up to 300MB/s which in real life can be well below that - for large files; i.e. there should be a strong emphasis on up to - especially when connected via USB.

@grawity_u1686 here is the link for that SSD, and I think it uses TLC flash.

@JoepvanSteen SSD is about 70% full and it's on NTFS

It's a bit suspicious that the product brief for this model doesn't list the flash type, specifies only the expected read performance but not write performance, and even the guaranteed TBW is just "N/A". Given it's from the "Green" line, I'm really tempted to assume that it is a QLC SSD, for which the write speed you're getting would actually be normal.

@grawity_u1686 But as I say sometimes you do get to see speeds like 300-400 MB/s on the same SSD, what can be the reason for this?

@TejasDahake Because the SLC cache is not filled up yet? Can you be more specific about "sometimes"? Do you mean like the speed drop after a certain time in one time of persistent writing, or do you mean like in some times of persistent writing (of similar size / pattern) it is slow, but in some times, it is fast (for the whole time).

@TejasDahake SSDs have a small amount of fast write cache. (Sometimes DRAM-then-SLC on the more expensive ones, more commonly only SLC.) For small writes, data goes to the cache first, then the SSD moves it to main flash whenever it has free time. When you start a large copy it'll first start filling the cache at SLC speeds, but as soon as it fills up, the rest necessarily has to go directly to main flash, and the speed will drop at that point.

Tejas - please [edit] your question to include the extra information you've provided in answers to comments.  Comments are ephemeral, and can disappear without warning.

@TomYan By 'sometimes' I mean it's sometimes of persistent writings it is slow and sometimes it is fast, but there is one weird thing I just noticed yesterday, that is the speed ramps upto 400 MB/s for a very few milliseconds, half of a second perhaps and then comes down to 30 MB/s and it just stays at 30 MB/s all the time, I think from this we can say that at least the connector is maybe not faulty, i.e if it is able to achieve 300MB/s even for some milliseconds then I guess at least for that time it is working as USB 3.0.

@TejasDahake well a short period of spike in speed is often an "illusion" caused by system write buffer.
